# Best puzzles of 2019 Q2 (April - June)?

Tags: discussion, best-of

*This question is part of the [best-puzzle award series](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of).*

---

> ### What are your nominations for the best puzzles, here on Puzzling.SE, of the second quarter ( April / May / June) 2019?

Suggested guidelines for nomination:

- Nominate each individual puzzle in a separate answer, so they can be upvoted/downvoted separately.
- No more than 3 nominations per person.
- Don't nominate your own puzzles.
- Before you nominate a puzzle, check to see if someone else has already nominated it. If they have, then add to that nomination as a comment (or edit it) instead of nominating the same puzzle again.
- **In your nomination, explain what it is that (in your opinion) makes the nominated puzzle such a good one.**

---

> Some lists to help jog your memory (your nomination doesn't have to be from these lists):
>
> - Algorithmically selected "best of":
>
>   - [***Popular puzzles***, both in score and in vote to view ratio, from 2019 Q2](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/509699/popular-puzzles-quaterly?year=2019&month=04#query-results)
>   - [Well received puzzles ***you may have missed*** from 2019 Q2](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/871694/puzzles-you-may-have-missed-quaterly?year=2019&month=04#query-results)
> - Best by votes/views:
>
>   - [Questions with the most ***votes*** from 2019 Q2](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106579?StartDate=2019/04/01#query-results)
>   - [Questions with the most ***views*** from 2019 Q2](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106705?StartDate=2019/04/01#query-results)
>   - [Questions with the highest-voted ***answers*** from 2019 Q2](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106709?StartDate=2019/04/01#query-results)

---

<sub>Meta-meta issues:</sub>

- <sub>Is this kind of thing allowed on SE?</sub>

  - <sub>Yes, [Photography SE](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/weekly-featured-image-ongoing-contest) and [Sci-fi/Fantasy SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3142/31394) do something very similar.</sub>
- <sub>What's the point?</sub>

  - <sub>To highlight and encourage good practice in a way that goes beyond upvotes.</sub>
  - <sub>To work towards building a 'hall of fame' of some of the best puzzles on the site (perhaps to reside on a future puzzling.SE blog) - think of it as our 'greatest hits album'.</sub>
  - <sub>To prompt members to put forward their own reflections on what makes a high-quality puzzle.</sub>

Answer (score 19):

## [How can this shape perfectly cover a cube?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84967/how-can-this-shape-perfectly-cover-a-cube) by [plasticinsect](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/52343/plasticinsect)

Because, of course, how the heck can this shape perfectly cover a cube??!!

[image]

It also gets a bonus point with the marvelous answer by [Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876/deusovi) and the breathtaking animation by [Wossname](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/1667/wossname)!

Comment: Nice one indeed! If PuzzleSE wouldn't have an icon yet, that would totally qualify!

Answer (score 9):

### [Can White Castle?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85221/can-white-castle/) by [shoopi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/21766/shoopi)

An amazing chess problem with several twists built into it - what starts out looking like a question with an obvious answer becomes increasingly unclear. The final result (which I won't spoil here!) involves *multiple* arguments about the entire history of the game up to the given point.

I was blown away when the answer was revealed, because I was convinced that the correct answer would turn out to be the opposite (and I had been attempting to write a proof of that fact for a while). And I wasn't the only one! Check out greenturtle3141's answer for a full explanation of how convoluted this puzzle can get.

Comment: Also worth a shout out, is another retrograde analysis chess puzzle by shoopi, [Checkmate in 1 on a Tangled Board](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85541/checkmate-in-1-on-a-tangled-board).

Comment: Noticed this topic on the "hot meta questions", and actually copied this very same puzzle's link on my clipboard before coming here. The "tangled" problem was quite intricate, too, but this one was an outright work of art.